# What are the conditions under which a Lion can pounce and rake?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, attack

A [lion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lion.htm) has the pounce extraordinary ability. It says that a lion can make a full attack including two rake attacks upon a charge. Which interpretation is correct?

1. A lion charges and gets five attacks (2 claws, 1 bite and 2 rakes)
2. A lion charges gets 2 claw attacks and a bite attack. If the bite attack hits and a grapple is initiated the lion also gets two rake attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A pouncing lion can make 5 attacks without grappling

The extraordinary ability [pounce](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#pounce) says, "When a creature with this special attack makes a charge, it can follow with a full attack—including rake attacks if the creature also has the rake ability" (*Monster Manual* 313). There're few reasons for the pounce ability to mention rake attacks if it weren't making an exception as to how rake attacks work normally.

With this in mind, a creature that possesses the extraordinary ability rake—like a [lion](http://dndsrd.net/monstersAnimal.html#lion) (274–5)—can charge, pounce, and use its rake attacks *without* obeying the normal rules for the rake ability, reproduced below:

> A creature with this special attack gains extra natural attacks when it grapples its foe. Normally, a monster can attack with only one of its natural weapons while grappling, but **a monster with the rake ability usually gains two additional claw attacks that it can use only against a grappled foe**. Rake attacks are not subject to the usual –4 penalty for attacking with a natural weapon in a grapple. (313–14)

Were the pounce ability *not* to make an exception for the rake ability, to bring its rake attacks to bear against a foe, a lion, for example, on a [charge](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#charge) would make its two claw attacks ***then*** its bite attack ***then***, if that's successful, make its grapple attempt due to its extraordinary ability [improved grab](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#improved-grab) (310) ***then***, if that's successful, take the grapple option [Attack Your Opponent](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grapple-attack-your-opponent) (*Player's Handbook* 156) for its rake attacks against the grappled foe, and the lion—were its foe not dead—would end its turn in a grapple. (This writer is familiar with the one-handed grapple rules present in the description of the improved grab ability, but this writer's keeping things simple.)

Note that a lion *can* still do that whole claw-claw-bite-grab-rake-rake routine above if it *wants* to—and it *will* in many situations—, but the exception made by the pounce ability for the lion's rake ability means that a lion isn't *forced* to if the lion wants to bring to bear all of its natural weapons yet *not* begin a grapple for whatever reason—like the lion wants to be able to make a quick getaway or the lion's outnumbered.

For example, a lion can charge a one commoner in a group of commoners in tight formation and—spectacularly!—because of the pounce ability leave *five* of those commoners dying, the lion having spent its first claw attack on the target of its charge, its second claw attack on another adjacent commoner, its bite on a third, one of its rake attacks on a fourth, and its other rake attack on a fifth.