# Clarification on the number of attacks a leopard receives

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, animals

On page 274 of the 3.5 Monster Manual the leopard is stated to have:

Attack: Bite +6 melee (1d6+3)
Full Attack: Bite +6 melee (1d6+3) and 2 claws +1 melee (1d3+1)

It also has the special attacks:

Improved Grab (Ex): To use this ability, a leopard must hit
with its bite attack. It can then attempt to start a grapple as a free
action without provoking an attack of opportunity. If it wins the
grapple check, it establishes a hold and can rake.

Pounce (Ex): If a leopard charges a foe, it can make a full attack,
including two rake attacks.

Rake (Ex): Attack bonus +6 melee, damage 1d3+1.

Would someone please error check my understanding of this? 
1) The leopard charges a foe 
2) It takes its full attack Bite +6 melee (1d6+3) and 2 claws +1 melee (1d3+1)
AND due to its Pounce special attack it can also make two Rake attacks at +6 melee, damage 1d3+1 each.
3) Its bite hits and therefore starts a grapple as a free action without provoking an attack of opportunity. It wins the grapple check, establishes a hold and Rake(s).

So we have a full attack of 3 attacks plus 2 rakes from the pounce plus a further 2 rakes from hitting with its bite and winning the grapple check. For a total of 7 attacks. Is this correct?

Comment: Although it's about the lion and not the leopard, I'm pretty sure this is answered by the answer to [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140416/8610) Answers, however, can still address this idea directly, I guess, without it being a total duplicate.

Comment: Yes it does answer the question by referring to your previous answer regards the lion I deduce that under the circumstances the leopard could take a total of 7 attacks if it wanted but it doesn't have to, if for whatever reason, it doesn't wish to start a grapple.

Comment: Almost. I'll write an answer. Even if this question is later marked as a duplicate, maybe the answer will help someone else looking for this same information.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64947/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pounce special ability of the [leopard](http://dndsrd.net/monstersAnimal.html#leopard) says, "If a leopard charges a foe, it can make a full attack, including two rake attacks" (*Monster Manual* 274).

This supplements but doesn't override the extraordinary ability [rake](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#rake) that says, "A monster with the rake ability must begin its turn grappling to use its rake—it can’t begin a grapple and rake in the same turn" (313-14).

In other words, when it pounces the leopard can get as many as 5 attacks—including 2 rakes—and even end its turn in a grapple, but it will *only* be able to rake twice. To bring again its two rake attacks to bear, the leopard needs to *either* pounce again *or* wait until after it's been in a grapple at least 1 turn.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this clarifies the situation I mistakenly believed seven attacks was possible in the round, I understand now why this is incorrect. I'll mark this question answered.